# dojo1.8 - unable to refresh the input text box of ComboBox when memory updated

Tags: dojo

dijit/form/ComboBox is a hybrid of a select element and a textbox.
I have:-
A select for 3 options for 3 memories
A ComboBox to be populated with selected memory each time select on "changed"
The item can be choosed in the ComboBox.
Again memory is selected and populated in ComboBox

All seem Ok but...
The ComoBox's textbox cannot be updated to reflect the change in memory. Or even it cannot be set to blank one.
I tried using value:""; or placeHolder:""; but to no avail.

```
meter_Select.on('change', function()
            {
                //registry.byId('batchSelect').destroyrescursive();
                console.debug("selected -> " + meter_Select.value);
                switch(meter_Select.value)
                {
                    case 'testdata1970_05': var memoStore2 =  new Memory({data:response2});
                    break;
                    case 'testdata1970_10': var memoStore2 =  new Memory({data:response3});
                    break;
                    case 'testdata2060_03': var memoStore2 =  new Memory({data:response1});
                }

                //memoStore2.put({"mfg_code":""});// it works but it needs to be moved to the top!

                var combx = registry.byId('cardSelect');// at first it will be undefined
                console.debug('ComboBox Select(1A) ='+combx);

                if(combx)//if combx exists or already defined
                {
                    combx.store = memoStore2;
                    combx.value = "";
                    combx.placeHolder = "Choose one of the batch...";
                    //combx.domAttr.set('cardSelect','displayedValue','');
                    console.debug('ComboBox Select(1C) ='+combx);
                    //domAttr.set('batchSelect','store','nemoStore2');
                } 
                else
                {// if combx does not exist or is not defined yet
                    combx = new ComboBox({
                    id: 'cardSelect',
                    store: memoStore2,
                    searchAttr: "mfg_code",
                    value :"",
                    placeHolder: "Choose one of the batch..."
                    }, "node_cardSelect");
                    console.debug('ComboBox Select(1B) ='+combx);
                }

                combx.startup();
```

You can check out at [jsFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/clementyap/9tNhN/33/)
Please advise. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use widgets' `set()` methods to change any of their internal properties, just like you should use `get()` to fetch them.

*You should (almost) never access widgets' properties directly* the way you've done.

In your case, you want to set the store and the value of the combobox, so:

```
    if(combx)
    {
        combx.set("store", memoStore2);
        combx.set("value", "");
    }
    else { ....
```

When you just do `combx.value`, you're just giving the widget a new internal value, but the widget is not made aware of it.

Using a `set` method gives the widget an opportunity to perform all the other necessary actions for the new value, such as rendering the label, perhaps some validation etc.

Comment: Hi Thanks It really helps fix it. Can you  direct me to the source where I can learn more about set and get? Is this from dojo/Stateful?

Comment: I'm not actually sure how well it is documented, it just seems to be a common convention across dojo/dijit/dojox. For example, _WidgetBase describes it: http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/quickstart/writingWidgets.html#attributes (but it's the same for e.g. dojo/store/xyz as well, and probably for dojo/Stateful too).